# joining two tables with multiple keys in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, outer-join

Table A:

| From_Node | To_Node | Avg_Time_real |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1975 | 3752 | 4.06 |
| 1975 | 4874 | 28 |
| 1975 | 4900 | 23.4 |
| 1975 | 5016 | 27.4 |
| 3752 | 5949 | 4 |
| 3752 | 6204 | 32 |
| 3752 | 6228 | 16 |
| 7100 | 1004 | 9 |
| 7100 | 1006 | 10 |
| 4874 | 1975 | 29 |
| 4874 | 3752 | 28 |

Table B:

| From_Node | To_Node | Avg_Time_Contract |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1975 | 3752 | 6 |
| 1975 | 4874 | 27 |
| 1975 | 4900 | 22 |
| 3752 | 5949 | 6 |
| 3752 | 6204 | 7 |
| 3752 | 6228 | 10 |
| 3752 | 6350 | 11 |
| 115 | 116 | 5 |
| 115 | 21469 | 7 |
| 4874 | 1975 | 30 |
| 4874 | 3752 | 31 |

How below can be performed, as I have data in excel with more than 20,000 rows.

**Output:**

| From_Node | To_Node | Avg_Time_real | Avg_Time_Contract |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1975 | 3752 | 4.06 | 6 |
| 1975 | 4874 | 28 | 27 |
| 1975 | 4900 | 23.4 | 22 |
| 1975 | 5016 | 27.4 | Null |
| 3752 | 5949 | 4 | 6 |
| 3752 | 6204 | 32 | 7 |
| 3752 | 6228 | 16 | 10 |
| 3752 | 6350 | Null | 11 |
| 7100 | 1004 | 9 | NUll |
| 7100 | 1006 | 10 | Null |
| 115 | 116 | Null | 5 |
| 115 | 21469 | Null | 7 |
| 4874 | 1975 | 29 | 30 |
| 4874 | 3752 | 28 | 31 |

I tried to remove duplicates from column to node but there are two keys, so unable to achieve the expected output. Can importing this dataset in sql and using outer join will give the expected result? But I am not sure how outer join can be performed using two keys with this case. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please provide your Excel version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Transform/Join Two Tables Into One

```
=LET(rData,A1:C12,cData,E1:G12,na,"Null",dlm,"@",
    rd,DROP(rData,1),ru,TAKE(rd,,1)&dlm&CHOOSECOLS(rd,2),
    cd,DROP(cData,1),cu,TAKE(cd,,1)&dlm&CHOOSECOLS(cd,2),
    cv,TAKE(cData,,-1),
    rui,VSTACK(TAKE(cv,1),IFNA(INDEX(DROP(cv,1),XMATCH(ru,cu)),na)),
    cf,FILTER(cd,ISNA(XMATCH(cu,ru))),
    cui,HSTACK(TAKE(cf,,2),
        IF(SEQUENCE(ROWS(cf)),na),TAKE(cf,,-1)),
VSTACK(HSTACK(rData,rui),cui))
```

[image]

**Edit**

- This following 'rearrangement' allows you to sort the data (see `d`).

```
=LET(rData,A1:C12,cData,E1:G12,na,"Null",dlm,"@",
    rd,DROP(rData,1),ru,TAKE(rd,,1)&dlm&CHOOSECOLS(rd,2),
    cd,DROP(cData,1),cu,TAKE(cd,,1)&dlm&CHOOSECOLS(cd,2),
    cv,TAKE(cData,,-1),
    rui,IFNA(INDEX(DROP(cv,1),XMATCH(ru,cu)),na),
    cf,FILTER(cd,ISNA(XMATCH(cu,ru))),
    cui,HSTACK(TAKE(cf,,2),
        IF(SEQUENCE(ROWS(cf)),na),TAKE(cf,,-1)),
    h,HSTACK(TAKE(rData,1),TAKE(cv,1)),
    d,SORT(VSTACK(HSTACK(rd,rui),cui)),
VSTACK(h,d))
```

Answer (score 0):

To join Avg_Time_Contract from Table B to Table A, in other words, get Avg_Time_Contract from Table B and show it in Table A using two keys can be achieved most easily in Excel using the `XLOOKUP` function and the ampersand `&` to add additional keys.

`=XLOOKUP(A2&B2,'Table B'!A:A&'Table B'!B:B,'Table B'!C:C,"",0)`

- The first argument references the two keys `From_Node` and `To_Node` in Table A, separated by an ampersand `&`.
- The second argument references the columns in Table B that corresponds to the two keys, separated by an amersand `&`.
- The third argument is the value to show if it can't find a match.
- The fourth argument is the type of match, with 0 = exact match.

Comment: This method assumes that Table A has all of the records/rows you need.